# Passing HTML Attributes and [DisplayFormat] using Html.EditorFor and Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am trying to use `Html.EditorFor` for a value where I need both a `DisplayFormat` attribute and an HTML attribute (specfically a CSS class) to be applied.

`Html.TextBox` ignores the `DisplayFormat` attribute, and `Html.EditorFor` will not let me pass Html attributes. Other than writing the HTML myself, what is the preferred solution here?

Comment: you can add the css class using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("MyDateTemplate")]
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/MyDateTemplate.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox(
    string.Empty, 
    Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
    new { @class = "foo" }
)%>
```

and in the main view:

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel()
```

or yet another one:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in your main view:

```
<div class="foo">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value) %>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
.foo input {
    /* define some rule here */
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems odd to be required to implement a control in order to pass HTML attributes, I don't do this anywhere else in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue just now.  If you are using an editor template for e.g. a date picker, you can simply do (using Razor):

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString), new { @class = "date" })
```

That will format the date using the value from the DisplayFormat attribute.