# ASP .Net MVC DisplayFormat NullDisplayText styling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently using `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="No Value")]` in one of my models but I'm looking for a way to have the rendered output, using `@Html.DisplayFor()`, to be styled differently to properties that have values (I wanted it greyed slightly to take away attention).

Is it possible to do this? I've tried putting HTML into the NullDisplayText string with no luck.

Comment: This link may give you an idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927488/passing-html-attributes-and-displayformat-using-html-editorfor-and-html-textbo

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that can target ONLY when the `NullDisplayText` is being display. Am I missing something?